# unable to install VMware workstation 14 in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation

---

### VMInstallHcmon

### Failed to install the hcmon driver.

### OK

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: What solutions have you tried and what were the results? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2130850 (basically reboot)

Comment: I dont have any other vmware software installed! that solution does not work for me!